# How to wait for this function to finish?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, discord.js

I need to wait for mapping function to finish before I send the data to the console. I know it has something to do with Promise. I've been trying for hours and I couldn't get it to work even after reading so much about promises and async functions...

````
async function inactiveMemberWarner() {
    var msg = "```javascript\nI have sent warnings to members that have been inactive for 2 weeks.\n\n"
    var inactiveMembers = '';
    var count = 0;
    var guildMembers = client.guilds.find(g => g.name === mainGuild).members;

    const keyPromises = await guildMembers.map(async (member) => {
        if (isMod(member)) {
            connection.query(`SELECT * from users WHERE userID='${member.id}'`, (err, data) => {
                if (data[0]) {
                    if (!data[0].warnedForInactivity && moment().isSameOrAfter(moment(data[0].lastMSGDate).add('2', 'week'))) {
                        count++;
                        var updateWarning = {warnedForInactivity: 1}
                        connection.query(`UPDATE users SET ? WHERE userID='${data[0].userID}'`, updateWarning);
                        member.send(`**[*]** WARNING: You've been inactive on \`\`${mainGuild}\`\` for 2 weeks. Members that have been inactive for at least a month will be kicked.`);
                        inactiveMembers += `${count}. ${member.user.tag}\n`;
                        return inactiveMembers;
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });

    await Promise.all(keyPromises).then(inactiveMembersData => console.log(inactiveMembers)); // RETURNS AN EMPTY STRING

    setTimeout(() => console.log(inactiveMembers), 5000); // RETURNS THE INACTIVE MEMBERS AFTER WAITING FOR 5 SECONDS (PRMITIVE WAY)
}

inactiveMemberWarner();
````

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Btw, why would you format a text message as Javascript? That makes no sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close, but not quite there.

First, some notes:

- `await` can be used on any value, but it is entirely pointless to use it on anything that isn't a Promise. Your `guildMembers.map(...);` returns an *array*, not a Promise.
- Mixing `await` and `.then(...)` works, but is kinda messy. You're already using `await` - why bother dealing with callbacks?
- Using `guildMembers.map(async ...)` like this will ensure that all the requests are fired more or less instantaneously, and they could finish in any order. This is fine, but it is kind of a race condition and results in a more or less random order of results.
- This is **not a good approach** even just conceptually! Any time you ever have to loop queries, try and investigate ways to do it in only one query. SQL is quite powerful.

The reason your current code doesn't work is because your `connection.query` function *escapes the async control flow*. What I mean by this is that the whole point of using async/await and Promises is basically to keep track of the callbacks locally, and to make use of promise chaining to dynamically add callbacks. If you call an async function which returns a Promise, you can now carry that Promise anywhere else in your code and attach a success handler to it dynamically: either with `.then()` or with the sugar `await`.

But the `connection.query` function doesn't return a Promise, it just has you pass another naked callback - this one is not being tracked by a Promise! The Promise doesn't have a reference to that callback, it can't know when that callback is getting called, and thus your async/await control flow is escaped and your promises resolve long before the queries have ran.

You can resolve this by making a new Promise in the async function:

````
async function inactiveMemberWarner() {
    var msg = "```javascript\nI have sent warnings to members that have been inactive for 2 weeks.\n\n"
    var inactiveMembers = '';
    var count = 0;
    var guildMembers = client.guilds.find(g => g.name === mainGuild).members;

    const keyPromises = guildMembers.map(async (member) => {
        if (isMod(member)) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                connection.query(`SELECT * from users WHERE userID='${member.id}'`, (err, data) => {
                    if (err) reject(err); //make errors bubble up so they can be handled
                    if (data[0]) {
                        if (!data[0].warnedForInactivity && moment().isSameOrAfter(moment(data[0].lastMSGDate).add('2', 'week'))) {
                            count++;
                            var updateWarning = {warnedForInactivity: 1}
                            connection.query(`UPDATE users SET ? WHERE userID='${data[0].userID}'`, updateWarning);
                            member.send(`**[*]** WARNING: You've been inactive on \`\`${mainGuild}\`\` for 2 weeks. Members that have been inactive for at least a month will be kicked.`);
                            resolve(`${count}. ${member.user.tag}\n`;);
                        }
                    } else resolve(""); //make sure to always resolve or the promise may hang
                });
            });
        }
    });

    let inactiveMembersData = await Promise.all(keyPromises); // Returns an array of inactive member snippets.
    inactiveMembers = inactiveMembersData.join(""); //join array of snippets into one string
}

inactiveMemberWarner();
````

This will work, but there is a **much much much better way**. SQL supports the [IN](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp) operator, which allows you to have conditions like `WHERE userID IN (list_of_ids)`. In other words, you can do this in *one query*. You can even specify more conditions, such as `warnedForInactivity = 0` and `lastMSGDate BETWEEN (NOW() - INTERVAL 14 DAY) AND NOW()`. This way you can offload all of your current processing logic onto the SQL server - something that you should try to do virtually *every single time you can*. It would simplify this code a lot too. I won't go any further as it's out of scope for this question but feel free to ask another if you can't figure it out.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and the code! I'll definitely start making good use of SQL in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I can't test this, but this is what normally works for me is when wanting to wait on smt:

````js
async function inactiveMemberWarner() {
    new Promise(function(cb,rj){
        var msg = "```javascript\nI have sent warnings to members that have been inactive for 2 weeks.\n\n"
        var inactiveMembers = '';
        var count = 0;
        var guildMembers = client.guilds.find(g => g.name === mainGuild).members;
        const keyPromises = await guildMembers.map(async (member) => {
            if (isMod(member)) {
                connection.query(`SELECT * from users WHERE userID='${member.id}'`, (err, data) => {
                    if (data[0]) {
                        if (!data[0].warnedForInactivity && moment().isSameOrAfter(moment(data[0].lastMSGDate).add('2', 'week'))) {
                            count++;
                            var updateWarning = {warnedForInactivity: 1}
                            connection.query(`UPDATE users SET ? WHERE userID='${data[0].userID}'`, updateWarning);
                            member.send(`**[*]** WARNING: You've been inactive on \`\`${mainGuild}\`\` for 2 weeks. Members that have been inactive for at least a month will be kicked.`);
                            inactiveMembers += `${count}. ${member.user.tag}\n`;
                            cb(inactiveMembers);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        cb('No Members');
    }).then(inactiveMembersData => console.log(inactiveMembers)); // SHOULD RETURNS THE INACTIVE MEMBERS
}

inactiveMemberWarner();
````